# How can I determine the actual inner and outer margins

Tags: margins

I somehow have the feeling this is a dumb question, but I just can't find anything :-(

How can I determine the actual values of the inner and outer margins of my document, or still better: the right and left margins of the current page?

Background is that I'm working on a package to manage music examples, and one of the kinds these come are multi-page pdf files.
Additional to other methods I would like to add an option to automatically offset the included pdf pages depending on being on an odd or even page.

For this I would like to read out the margins of the current page.

Comment: The packages [`layouts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layouts) and [`layout`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layout) can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these suggestions helps me: I don't need to determine if I'm on an odd side (I have this already), and I don't need to *display* layout values, but I have to *read* and use them. So it would be best if these values were stored in counters that I can simply read out.

Comment: @uli_1973: When you use the `\layout` package, not only does it display the values, but it also tells you the name of the length registers that contain those values.

Comment: @Peter: I'm sorry, obviously I didn't think far enough. Of course `\layout` doesn't give me directly what I want, but provides me with the tools to do so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reference point (unless changed with `\hoffset` and `\voffset`) is `1in` in and `1in` down from the top left of the page.

Relative to that point the left margin in LaTeX  is `\oddsidemargin` on odd pages and `\evensidemargin` on even pages. The total paper width is `\paperwidth`  so the right margin on an odd page is `\paperwidth` - `\textwidth` - `\oddsidemargin` - `1in`.

Answer (score 10):

To *read* and *use* margin lengths and the like, check this MWE. The `\layout`command of the package `layout` show all the relevant lengths about margins, so IMHO the comment of Marco Daniel it is really a good suggestion. Another could be the use of the package `geometry` to fix yourself the margin values.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
% \layout 
The text width is now \the\textwidth

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

The odd side margin is now \the\oddsidemargin ~
\rule{\oddsidemargin}{0.4pt}

The even side margin is now \the\evensidemargin ~
\rule{\evensidemargin}{0.4pt} 

The top margin is now \the\topmargin  ~
\rule{\topmargin}{0.4pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can only accept one answer. Yours was more practical to get a feeling for the syntax, but the other one provides important information about the reference point.

Answer (score -1):

missing a `~` in the text, in the previus answer

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
% \layout
```

The text width is now `\the\textwidth` ~

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I don't think the `~` is necessary because the following rule goes to a new line.